# How to align different font-size headers?

Tags: html, css

They just don't want to be on baseline for some reason in flex row:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4Lmdqnj6/

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 22px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>H1</h1>
  <h2>H2</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Please make your example minimal. If your question is about HTML and CSS, don’t include JavaScript in the fiddle. Your fiddle doesn’t even run out of the box.

Comment: u have align-items: baseline on the flex items instead of the flex container... also vertical-align: baseline is the default... not needed

Comment: Dear god, what is that mess of a fiddle...

Comment: sorry, i see it different for some reason

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can replace all your css code by

```
div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: baseline;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 22px;
}

h2 {
    font-weight: 16px;
}
```

Flex allows you to specify `baseline` for `align-items`

Answer (score 0):

Change  `CSS` property for main `wrapper` `align-items: baseline;` & Remove other `CSS` for `H1` & `H2`

```css
div {
 display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline; /* Change This Property*/
}

h1 {
  font-size: 22px;
  
}
h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
   
}
```

```html
<div>
        <h1>H1</h1>
        <h2>H2</h2>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

added below css

```
h1,
h2{margin:0}
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 22px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

h1,
h2{margin:0}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>H1</h1>
  <h2>H2</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`align-items` is a property than belongs to the flex container, not the flexed items, see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for a quick reference or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox for a tutorial.

This code achieves the desired effect:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Bigger</h1>
  <h2>smaller<h2>
</div>
```